# In the optimal model, do I need to change 'REML=FALSE' to 'REML=TRUE'?

Tags: r, mixed-model, model-comparison

I did the model comparison using these three models:

```
lmer1 <- lmer(peak_Mid ~ (1|item) + (1+vowel|speaker) + gender*vowel*language, data=data.frame, REML=FALSE, na.action=na.omit)
lmer2 <- lmer(peak_Mid ~ (1|item) + (1+vowel|speaker) + gender + vowel + Language + language:vowel + Language:gender + vowel:gender, data=data.frame, REML=FALSE, na.action=na.omit)
anova(lmer1,lmer2)
lmer3 <- lmer(peak_Mid ~ (1|item) + (1+vowel|speaker) + gender + vowel + language, data=data.frame, REML=FALSE, na.action=na.omit)
anova(lmer2,lmer3)
```

Then I run Tukey's HSD Post-hoc test based on the optimal model without changing 'REML=FALSE' to 'REML=TRUE'. The question is whether I need to change this before running the Tukey's HSD Post-hoc test? In my opinion, I don't need to change it as if I change, it means I didn't get the Tukey's HSD Post-hoc test based on the optimal model from model comparison as I changed the formula. What do you think?

Comment: Note that your statistical audience here is limited to those who understand the code. Questions dominated by code are often unclear, not least because you have to be crystal clear on whether you want (a) statistical advice (b) coding advice or (c) both. (b) is off-topic here.

Comment: Also tell us more on HSD tests you run.

Comment: Hi Nick, I intended to ask the statistical advice as I don't think it is appropriate to change the optimal model to 'REML=TRUE' while I use 'REML=FALSE' in model comparison.

Comment: Hi Tim, the HSD tests, I have run was the Tukey's HSD Post-hoc  tests using lsmeans package based on the optimal model.